# minimize image size in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

i wanted to add a image on my canvas .the width and height of the canvas is 400X400.and size of the image is 298x300.i want it to have the size of 30x30 when it will be drawn on the canvas.so i gave it width and height inside script tag.but it is not affecting the original size of the image .it covers up the whole canvas(even only half of it is shown).how can i fix this?

```
![<html>
<head>
<style>
#mycanvas{
width:400;
height:400;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function draw(){
  var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img=new Image();
  img.src="lol1.jpg";
  img.style.width="30px";
  img.style.height="30px";
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

window.onload=draw;
</script>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>]
```

[image]

Comment: this answer you can have just by reading the documentation. Asking such a question shows a lack of respect for S.O. members. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-images

Comment: i had a question and i asked for expert help..if someone thinks it is worth helping they will answer my question.i am learning all by myself and i will appreciate their help.i am not seeing any offensive gesture here..and i didn't understand what point you are trying to make..

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,30,30);
```

4th parameter is width, 5th is height.

Comment: -1 for answering a bad question/contributing to noise.

Comment: @GameAlchemist unless the answer is actually incorrect, this is an inappropriate downvote

Comment: ok after a few refresh the image appears..i think i have to delete the post .thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Alnitak : if you think a one-line answer to a question that shows that the O.P. didn't read the documentation is ok, feel free to upvote.

Comment: I already did, but I re-iterate, your downvote on a correct answer just because you think the question is "noise" is inappropriate.  Down votes should be for answers that are incorrect or misleading, not as a means of punishing the user.  By all means do downvote the question, though!